# PHP checking remote server port and count connections

Tags: php, sql-server

I have made a PHP to check an open port locally and count how many connections that is connect and print it. It works great locally but once i want to check remotely (my web server is on diff server) it just failed to get the result. The remote server is server 2012 with port 80 close. Below is the code.

```
    $handle = fopen("Includes/online.txt", "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize("Includes/online.txt"));
    fclose($handle);
    $contents = explode("\n", $contents);
    //print_r($contents);
if (!$contents || (time() - $contents[1]) > $ocs) {
    $command = "netstat -p TCP -n";
    exec($command,$status);
    //$status = PsExecute($command);
    //print_r($status);
    $status = array_slice($status, 5);
    $connections = array();
    foreach ($status as $stat => $s) {
    $c = preg_split('/ /', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ($c[3] == 'ESTABLISHED') {
        $ipp = preg_split('/:/', $c[1], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $ripp = preg_split('/:/', $c[2], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);


            for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++ ){

        if ($ipp[1] == $config['server'][$i]['port']) {
        $connections[] = array('type'=>$c[0],'ip'=>$ipp[0],'port'=>$ipp[1],'rip'=>$ripp[0],'rport'=>$ripp[1],'con'=>$c[3]);

        }
        }
    }

    }

    $con = (!count($connections) ? 0 : count($connections))  ."\n". time();
    if ($fp = fopen('Includes/online.txt', 'w')) {
        fwrite ($fp, $con);
    }
    $con = array('online' => count($connections));
} else {

    $con = array('online' => $contents[0]);
}


//print_r($status);
```

Below is connection info.

```
$config['server'] = array(array('ip'=>'ipxxx', 
'port'=>10201),array('ip'=>'ipxxx', 
'port'=>10202),array('ip'=>'ipxxx', 
'port'=>10203),array('ip'=>'ipxxx', 
'port'=>10204),array('ip'=>'ipxxx', 
'port'=>10205),array('ip'=>'ipxxx', 'port'=>10208));
 $ocs = "20";//in seconds it checks
```

The purpose of the code is to check an open port remotely at difference server (server 2012) and count the total connections and print it. I have failed to do that remotely. Is there any port that I need to open beside SQL server port for PHP successfully connect to the server? MSSQL is connected and I don't have any problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

To me it's unclear what you are asking for.

To check active TCP/IP connections on SQL-Server you can use there stored procedure `sp_who2` or this query:

```
select *  from sys.sysprocesses where net_library like 'TCP/IP%'
```

SQL-Server has default TCP/IP port 1433. The TCP/IP protocol must be enabled on server side.